# Mailchimp API changes v1/2 to v3 for interest groupings

Tags: mailchimp

Mailchimp's v2 API returned integers for groups and groupings (thankful they've clarified those terms into categories and interests!) but the v3 API returns hashes.

So my integrations that have stored the v2 ids now don't match using v3. It would have been polite if they'd returned the v2 id as well to at least make migration slightly easier.

If you only have access to the v3 api, is there any way to map these old ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need simultaneous access to both APIs or you'll need to convert your IDs before you migrate. v3.0 does not contain any of the v2.0 IDs for interests (groups) or categories (groupings).